# POST request to API

Tags: php, rest, post, moodle

So some quick background: I'm trying to teach myself to code, but right now I'm really a beginner. I'm trying to help out my younger brother's school with setting up a moodle-powered online course system featuring videos of full classes, and I've run into a snag with the school's preferred video host.

Basically, here's my problem:
The guys hosting the videos don't want to allow people to directly link to the videos, instead they built an API they want us to use that takes a POST request, then outputs a new URL, which expires after one use.

I've figured out how to use the API using POSTman or in the terminal

```
#for example: 
#  curl -F 
#     api_key='the api key they gave us' -F  
#     email='a user's email' -F  
#     destination='a subdirectory' 
#     'the target URL'
```

What I can't figure out, is how to automate this process so that teachers can input the link to their video on our host's site ('somesite.com/videos/teacherx/') directly in the moodle class editor (if possible), so that whenever a student is taking the class they can click a link that runs the script, does the POST request, and redirects them to the new temporary URL.

In case you can't tell, I have no idea what I'm doing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you make a function of the API request that returns the destination URL, and then redirect to it?

Comment: What do you have? How far did you come? Where is the error? Or are you just asking advice?

Comment: I'm just asking advice really, I just don't know how to tackle this problem.

User8889: I guess I could do that, yeah. Maybe make a form that the initial link is pasted into by teachers, (which then I guess gets stored in a 'target' variable) then have it output a link that when a student clicks it runs the function, and auto-redirects them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you'll need a text filter - basically search for text and replace it with something else when displaying.

See if your application is listed here : https://moodle.org/plugins/browse.php?list=category&id=7

If not then you will need to write your own filter - the instructions are here https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Filters

Maybe download the code for the screencast filter and see how that works :
https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=filter_screencast

Or you can look at the screencast code on github at https://github.com/TechSmith/Moodle-Screencast-Filter

Comment: That seems like it might help with my problem, (though the company hosting our videos is new, and just wrote the API for us, they usually only host live streams for conferences/webinars I think, so it looks like I'll have to write my own filter then.) 

So basically if I understand this, I'll just have the teachers copy/paste the video URL into the class, then I'll have the filter find it, grab it, and then when a student opens the class the filter will run the POST request, get the new temporary URL, and display it in that instance instead.

If I'm understanding correctly, that should work!

Comment: That's it in theory :)